# Counting elementary events and discrete triangular law

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

> A six-sided die is tossed twice. Let $X_i$ be the score obtained from the $i$th toss, $i = 1, 2$. Assume $X_1 \perp X_2$.
> (a) By counting elementary events (or otherwise), show that the pdf of the total score is the discrete triangular law:
> $$P(X_1 + X_2 = k) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{k - 1}{36} & \text{if} \ k = 2, \dots, 7, \\ \dfrac{12 - k + 1}{36} & \text{if} \ k = 7, \dots, 12. \end{cases}$$

The solution is as follows:

> The elementary events for this random experiment are the number pairs $(f, s)$, where $1 \le f, s \le 6$ and $f$ (resp. $s$) denotes the score from the first (resp. second) roll of the die. The elementary events are equi-probable, so $P(X_1 = f, X_2 = s) = 1/36$. If $Z = X_1 + X_2$, then the event $\{ Z = k \}$ corresponds to elementary events with $f + s = k$, where $k = 2, 3, \dots, 12$. These are the elementary events that lie on the upper-left to lower-right diagonals of the matrix whose entries are $(f, s)$. The number of elementary events in each such diagonal is $1$ for $k = 2$, $2$ for $k = 3, \dots$, $6$ for $k = 7$, $5$ for $k = 8, \dots$, and $1$ for $k = 12$. Therefore, for any $k \in \{ 2, \dots, 7 \}$, there are $k = 1$ elementary events, and for any $k \in \{ 7, \dots, 12 \}$, there are $13 - k$ elementary events. The result follows immediately from the fact that
> $$P(Z = k) = \dfrac{ \#\{ (f, s) : f + s = k \}}{36}.$$

I don't understand this solution from this part onwards:

> These are the elementary events that lie on the upper-left to lower-right diagonals of the matrix whose entries are $(f, s)$. The number of elementary events in each such diagonal is $1$ for $k = 2$, $2$ for $k = 3, \dots$, $6$ for $k = 7$, $5$ for $k = 8, \dots$, and $1$ for $k = 12$. Therefore, for any $k \in \{ 2, \dots, 7 \}$, there are $k = 1$ elementary events, and for any $k \in \{ 7, \dots, 12 \}$, there are $13 - k$ elementary events. The result follows immediately from the fact that
>
> $$P(Z = k) = \dfrac{ \#\{ (f, s) : f + s = k \}}{36}.$$

What does it mean that these are the elementary events that lie on the upper-left to lower-right diagonals of the matrix whose entries are $(f, s)$? What does it mean when it says that the number of elementary events in each such diagonal is $1$ for $k = 2$, $2$ for $k = 3, \dots$, $6$ for $k = 7$, $5$ for $k = 8, \dots$, and $1$ for $k = 12$? And why does this mean that, for any $k \in \{ 2, \dots, 7 \}$, there are $k = 1$ elementary events, and for any $k \in \{ 7, \dots, 12 \}$, there are $13 - k$ elementary events?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, this is better demonstrated by writing down the matrix of $(f, s)$:$$\begin{matrix}
(6,1)&(6,2)&(6,3)&(6,4)&(6,5)&(6,6)\\
(5,1)&(5,2)&(5,3)&(5,4)&(5,5)&(5,6)\\
(4,1)&(4,2)&(4,3)&(4,4)&(4,5)&(4,6)\\
(3,1)&(3,2)&(3,3)&(3,4)&(3,5)&(3,6)\\
(2,1)&(2,2)&(2,3)&(2,4)&(2,5)&(2,6)\\
(1,1)&(1,2)&(1,3)&(1,4)&(1,5)&(1,6)
\end{matrix}$$
Along any diagonal from the upper-left to lower-right the sum $f + s$ is seen to be a constant.

For the second question, take $k = 2$ for example. The corresponding diagonal crosses through $(2, 1)$ and $(1, 2)$, so the number of events for $k = 2$ is $2$.

Comment: I don't understand how this matrix makes sense. Shouldn't $(1, 1)$ be the first element of the matrix, and so on?

Comment: @ThePointer Conventionally you're right, but the solution seems to treat the matrix as a set of points on a Cartesian plane so that $(1,1)$ is placed at the bottom-left corner, so it's somewhat confusing without showing the matrix explicitly.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Can you please explain how you came to this matrix? I've read through the problem statement again, but I'm not sure why it demands that the matrix be constructed in this way.

Comment: @ThePointer Actually the matrix is *not* required to be constructed in this way only. One could place $(1,1)$ at the upper-left corner as it is usually done and change the upper-left to lower-right diagonals in the solution to lower-left to upper-right ones. I figured out the above construction of the matrix based on the diagonals mentioned in the solution.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me.